# Interrupting an IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, intentservice

Im creating an app, where I need to process data that can be huge and could take some time.

Now I read a lot of stuff on IntentService and I actually already implemented it as a communication class for handling REST calls, but now im trying to use it for long running data processing.

I added a progress indicator in the title bar, but now id like to be able to cancel the operation, when the user clicks it.

Is there some elegant way of doing this?(something like Thread.interrupt()) Currently I have a static boolean "running" and I have overriden the onStartCommand to

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("stop")) {
        running = false;
    }
    onStart(intent, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I find this cumbersome and not elegant and feel that I might be misusing the IntentService for something its not meant to do. Is there some more elegant way of doing this?

stopSelf() doesnt work for me as I need to interrupt what is being done. I tried it and the code just went on executing.

I thought of asynctask, but im worried that the task wont survive.(the operation can take as much as 15minutes)

Comment: You are right to avoid AsyncTasks for this: "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most)" from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `IntentService` is not really suitable for your purposes. Instead, you can extend `Service` directly (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) and clear message queue (`Handler` in this case) on particular start command and perform your finalization procedures.

Comment: Creating my own service seems to me a bit of an overkill. I dont really want parralel execution(in fact it would cause problems). But it seems to be the only clean way to go.

Comment: @Radovan I'm not talking about parallel execution - you're free to implement the same task queue as `IntentService` have. Just customize it to your needs

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I came up with for this situation was to add a field that the background thread (that the IntentService spins up for you) code checks and that is set in onDestory(), which will be called when you do a stopService() call on your IntentService class.

so in your IntentService:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "got on destroy, asking background thread to stop as well");
        mPleaseStop = true;
    }
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    while(true) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Doing some long running stuff here");
        if (mPleaseStop) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And then just call

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class))
```

And to be correct, you should make the setting and check synchronised too.

Comment: won't this keep the intentservice alive forever? how does the service escape the while loop when the execution of the long running task is complete?

Comment: I should have been more clear, the code I included is simply a basic example of how to interrupt the service, it's up to you to write your code to complete normally when it's not interrupted.

Comment: but intentservice uses a thread that completes only when the included task completes. how are you going to "complete" the task and exit the loop with your code?

Comment: That's what the boolean flag does.

Comment: oh sorry i got confused, the stopService call via intent calls the onDestroy method which sets the bool flag which then kills the task

Comment: This doesn't work if the service is sleeping.